# How to use htpasswd protection in Tomcat?

Tags: security, tomcat, .htpasswd, security-constraint

I have already created a user database file using Apache's htpasswd command. This file is now used by several other application like apache and subversion.

Users in are created like this:

```
htpasswd /path/to/users.htpasswd peter
```

This user file is global, not per directory.

How I can make Tomcat 6 use this same file as a security realm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Use Apache as a front end to the tomcat (using either mod_jk or mod_proxy_ajp) and the Apache do the authentication. You can find details on how to do so [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html)
2. If you want the tomcat to do the authentication, then you need ot use something else than the htpasswd file. There are 4 ways to save the users' credentials - using database, JNDI/LDAP, an XML file or a JAAS provider. You can read about all the options in the [Realm Configuration HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html).

Answer (score 3):

Most similar to the htpasswd may be the [MemoryRealm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#MemoryRealm).
I had problems myself to find a simple example how to use it, so I'll post an easy example code here:

1. Set up a role, username and password in tomcat-users.xml
2. Your web.xml should contain something like:

   ```
      <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name> 
           My Protected WebSite 
         </web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern> /* </url-pattern>
         <http-method> GET </http-method>
         <http-method> POST </http-method>
       </web-resource-collection>
       <auth-constraint>
       <!-- the same like in your tomcat-users.conf file -->
         <role-name> test </role-name>
       </auth-constraint>
     </security-constraint>
      <login-config>
       <auth-method> BASIC </auth-method>
       <realm-name>  Basic Authentication </realm-name>
     </login-config>
     <security-role>
       <description> Test role </description>
       <role-name> test </role-name>
     </security-role>
   ```
3. Add this to your server.xml file:

   ```
   <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm"></Realm>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

To secure access to your Tomcat webapp, you can implement your simple security constraint (e.g. in `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/*/WEB-INF/web.xml`) as below (just add it before `</web-app>` ending):

```
<!-- This security constraint protects your webapp interface. -->
<login-config>
  <!-- Define the Login Configuration -->
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Webapp</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <!-- Specifying a Secure Connection -->
  <user-data-constraint>
    <!-- transport-guarantee can be CONFIDENTIAL (forced SSL), INTEGRAL, or NONE -->
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<!-- Authorization, see: tomcat-users.xml --> 
<security-role>
  <role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>
```

> The login-config element contains the `auth-method` element, which specifies the authentication method that we use, which is `BASIC`. The `security-constraint` element contains 3 elements: `web-resource-collection`, `auth-constraint`, and `user-data-constraint`. The web-resource-collection specifies the parts of our application that require authentication. The `/*` indicates that the whole application requires authentication. The auth-constraint specifies the role that a user needs to have in order to access the protected resources. The user-data-constraint's transport-guarantee can be `NONE`, `CONFIDENTIAL` or `INTEGRAL`. We set it to `NONE`, which means that redirecting to `SSL` is not required when you try to hit the protected resource.

Also make sure that you've line:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />
```

inside your `conf/server.xml` (`Engine` section).

If you have not changed any configuration files, please examine the file `conf/tomcat-users.xml` in your installation (`locate tomcat-users.xml`). That file must contain the credentials to let you use Tomcat webapp.

For example, to add the manager-gui role to a user named `tomcat` with a password of `s3cret`, add the following to the config file listed above:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

Then you can access your webapps manager from `/manager/html` (e.g. reloading after config changes).

Read more: [Manager App HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html).

Then restart your Tomcat and when accessing your webapp, it should ask you for the right credentials.

See also:

- [HTTP Basic Authentication in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncbo/index.html) at Oracle site
- [Specifying an Authentication Mechanism in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncbn/index.html) at Oracle site
- [Realm Configuration HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html) at Apache Tomcat site
- [Setting up role based security in tomcat](http://www.thecoderscorner.com/team-blog/hosting-servers/17-setting-up-role-based-security-in-tomcat)
- [How do I use Basic authentication with Tomcat?](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-basic-authentication-with-tomcat.html)